"Low system resources may affect your audio quality" during zoom calls
I often get "Low system resources may affect your audio quality" message during zoom calls, there're often indeed audio issues when I get the message.
Checking task manager, I generally can't see exceptional load.
I've browser, outlook and some documents open in the background, but nothing with really high demand.
I've Windows 10 on an HP EliteBook 850 G7 (Intel i7-10810U, 32 GB RAM). Both OS and zoom are kept up to date.
It's a 3 year old pc but received fresh OS just a few months ago.
The issue already existed before and not improved after reinstall.
Is there anything I can do to improve experience?


My experience has been that Zoom is quite demanding of resources, and having a browser open as well can overload the system. Also, I've found using HD video from the webcam is an extra burden.

Your Intel GPU is being reasonably heavily used, which is putting your CPU into a thermal throttling mode of 0.9GHz which is less than the 1.6GHz base speed the CPU has been configured at.
Restricted CPU performance would be considered a "low system resource" in my book.
The i7-10810U is rated up to 1.6GHz base clock with boost up to 4.9GHz, though it appears your system builder has configured its reported speed down to 1.1GHz, presumably due to system thermal consideration.
If you can open up your laptop you may want to look into cleaning dust out of fans and heatsink assemblies.
Otherwise a cooling mat may help reduce temperatures and allow the CPU to clock higher.
Another alternative might be to configure Zoom to use the nvidia GPU, which may shift the heat away from the CPU and again allow it to hit a higher speed.

I have a zbook fury.  I will add, make sure you have full power going to the laptop.  You probably already knew this.  My HP throttles down when running on either battery OR a lesser power source.. but WHOA .92ghz sucks!  I never throttle that low that I notice.. I bet Mokubai is right about cleaning.

thanks! Setting zoom to use Nvidia GPU solved the issue! Interestingly just based on that change my CPU now runs at 1.8-2.0 GHz frequency.
